# How do you mod polynomials by another polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, coding-theory

I'm struggling to understand the concept behind questions of the form $f(x) = g(x) \bmod h(x)$.
The example I have infront of me states

> "... *note that $x\cdot x = x+1$ since $x^2 \bmod (x^2+x+1) = x+1$*"

It looks super simple but I think I'm missing just one small key bit of information yet I can't find it anywhere?

I forgot to include that they are in a field of characteristic 2

Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: You can think of $a \equiv b \pmod c$ as meaning "there exists a $k$ such that $a = b + kc$. This clearly generalises to polynomials (often you allow $k$ to also be a polynomial, though). Another way to think about it, if you know any basic ring theory, is to say that they lie in the same coset of the principal ideal generated by $x^2 + x + 1$ in this polynomial ring. Basically it means that you should think of $x^2 + x + 1$ as being $0$, so you can add or subtract multiples of it as often as you want. However Will's answer is correct about the specifics of what's happening here.

Comment: I wonder whether you saw $f(x) \equiv g(x) \bmod h(x)$ and mistook it for $f(x) = g(x) \bmod h(x).$ If you construe "mod" in the traditional sense dating back to Carl Gauss's book published in 1801, then $f(x) \equiv g(x) \bmod h(x)$ is parsed as $\big( f(x) \equiv g(x)\big) \bmod h(x),$ and that means $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both leave the same remainder when divided by $h(x).$ There's also the modern notation, I suspect not introduced until about 1950 or '60, in which $a\bmod b$ means the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy If I've understood you correctly, then I was meaning the very last bit where you wrote "...the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$." so I was trying to figure out how to divide $x^2$ by $x^2+x+1$ and I also had not realised that $-x-1$ can be seen as $x+1$ because $-1$ can be treated as $1$ as mentioned by Dark Malthorp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong, unless the coefficients are in a field of characteristic 2.

$$ x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {x^2 + x + 1} $$
$$ x^2  \equiv -x-1 \pmod {x^2 + x + 1} $$

Answer (score 2):

To understand modding by polynomials, first let's recall how modding by numbers works: We say $a \equiv b \mod n$ if $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$. For polynomials, it works exactly the same way:$$
f(x) \equiv g(x) \mod h(x) \Longleftrightarrow f(x)-g(x) \text{ is a multiple of }h(x)
$$
There's a well-defined notion of "is a multiple of" for polynomials, just like there is for integers, and just like integers, the set of polynomials that are multiples of $h(x)$ is an ideal subring of the full polynomial ring, thus equivalence mod $h(x)$ respects addition and multiplication.

In this example, $$
x+1 \equiv x^2 \mod (x^2 + x+1)
$$
is saying $x^2 - (x+1)$ is a multiple of $x^2+x+1$. Since you're in a field with characteristic 2, $1=-1$, so this is true (in fact, $x^2 - (x+1) = x^2 + x + 1$).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title, to find $g(x) \bmod h(x)$, use [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) and write $g(x) = q(x)h(x)+r(x)$, with $r(x)=0$ or $\deg r(x) < \deg h(x)$. Then $r(x)$ is the reduction you seek: $r(x)= g(x) \bmod h(x)$.